# java run too fast when i call new constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I'm currently entertaining myself and experimenting in Java with a 2D running game.
I lately add Items for the player to pick up. There are coins, speed booster and hearts of life.

But i realized I couldn't spawn more than 1 of these Items because the conditions to make them disappear once the player caught them is changed.
I figured out I should use a constructor like that :

```
private static boolean presentspeed = true;

public ItemSpeed(int x, int y)
{
    if(presentspeed )
    {
        while(y < 560)
        {
            y += 1;
        }
        Drawer.drawImage(Load.Speed.getImage(), x+DrawAll.Xbackground, y, null);
        if(Player.x <= x+40 && Player.x >= x && Player.getY()+Player.textureY == y+40)
        {
            Player.BoostTimer += 100;
            presentspeed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you may see, the boolean **presentspeed** is turned false when the player is on the Item so that the item disappear.
This worked when this function was just a function in a **Items.java** file (but i could only spawn 1 item because the others would disappear with the first one)

But now that I made that into a constructor (in a **ItemSpeed.java** file) the game is running too fast, the player can't even touch the keyboard to begin he's already lost.

Here's where a call the Items to spawn

```
    public static void drawItems()
{
    new ItemSpeed(600, 500);
    new ItemSpeed(650, 500);

    Items.Life(805, 500);
    Items.Coins(1400, 500);
}
```

You can see both with the constructor and without.

My question : What should I do to make it work properly, 'cause it technically work but it's not playable (and my computer isn't the problem)

Comment: These are concurrency issues, and these will most probably not be solved here. Please read something about creating concurrent animations in Java.

Comment: Your loop while(y < 560) has very little purpose, it is equivalent to just setting y = 560; Since the only thing it does is increment until it reaches that value. Other than that, it is not suitable to put this kind of logic in a constructor, the purpose of it is just to create and initialize to object, nothing else. You should reconsider how you are doing things.

Comment: I am unable to follow the logic of the code. You seem to be creating 2 objects in drawItems but not keeping an instance to them and as a result they will be left dangling and cleaned later.
Also all speed objects share the boolean 'presentSpeed' so all speed objects will disappear once presentSpeed is triggered and never show again..

Comment: The while(y < 560) is only here for future coding, I'm planning to make the items spawn on a certain height depending on what's under them (for examples if there's a plateform the item can lay on, it will stop at the platform) I just used 560 'cause it's the ground level. Then I wanna thank all of you, I just was doing it all wrong the constructor is not what i should use :) I'll think of something else to make it work, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is just all **wrong**. You need to move this logic to a single method, a method that is invoked by some kind of main class / **engine**. The methods that contain this kind of logic (might be separate for each game object) should be invoked by the engine during a certain intervals.

**For example, if you want to update your game state 30 times per second, you should have your engine run a method every 1/30th of a second, in this method you should iterate all your game objects and run their respective game logic methods that will perform calculations and repaints. Speed/Velocity/Collisions/Redraw.**

If you create an game object **interface** you can add all your **Game objects to a list** which is easy for your **engine to iterate**.

If you are unsure of what this means I recommend that you read some tutorials about game making before you go any further.

Comment: That was what i did in the first place. all there is in the constructor is what orriginally was a method in a Item.java file. Nut I couldn't make mutiples Items 'cause they're all on the condition of the presetspeed boolean. The Idea of using constructor is maybe not what i should have done after all... :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers if you find them reasonable and good luck with your game! :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to include the drawing block of code into a `while` loop like this?:

```
private static boolean presentspeed = true;

public ItemSpeed(int x, int y)
{
    if(presentspeed )
    {
        while(y < 560)
        {
            y += 1;
            Drawer.drawImage(Load.Speed.getImage(), x+DrawAll.Xbackground, y, null);
            if(Player.x <= x+40 && Player.x >= x && Player.getY()+Player.textureY == y+40)
            {
                Player.BoostTimer += 100;
                presentspeed = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The previous `while` loop would run instantaneously and would not have any effect.

Overall this code looks wrong on so many levels. Don't do such complex computation in constructor - it's not a place for it. There will be concurrency issues for sure.